# System.NotImplementedException : "The method or operation is not implemented." FoolProofValidation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, foolproof-validation

In my MVC4 application I'm using MVC FoolProof library

In my Metadata class I have

```
public class R_DealsMetaData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public bool CodeGenerated { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please Enter Description")]
    [Display(Name="Promotion Name:")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select one Option")]
    [Display(Name = "Deal Buy:")]
    public int Buy { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select one Option")]
    [Display(Name = "Deal Free:")]
    public int Free { get; set; }

    public Nullable<bool> Status { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public System.DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Expiry Date")]
    [Display(Name = "Promotion Expiry Date:")]
    public System.DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }

    [RequiredIf("Type", "P", ErrorMessage = "Please select")]
    public Nullable<int> PointEarnType { get; set; }

    [RequiredIf("PointEarnType", 2, ErrorMessage = "Please enter value")]
    public string PointEarnMealText { get; set; }

    [RequiredIf("Type","V",ErrorMessage="Please enter")]
    public string VolumeBuyText { get; set; }

    [RequiredIf("Type","V",ErrorMessage="Please enter")]
    public string VolumeEarnText { get; set; }

}
```

But at my controller post method an exception has been thrown on `db.SaveChanges`

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(R_Deals r_deals)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.R_Deals.Add(r_deals);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Following are the details of exception

```
An unexpected exception was thrown during validation of 'PointEarnType' when invoking     Foolproof.RequiredIfAttribute.IsValid. See the inner exception for details.
```

Stack Trace Details

```
    [NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.]
   Foolproof.ModelAwareValidationAttribute.IsValid(Object value) +59
   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.IsValid(Object value, ValidationContext validationContext) +115
   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.GetValidationResult(Object value, ValidationContext validationContext) +29
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.ValidationAttributeValidator.Validate(EntityValidationContext entityValidationContext, InternalMemberEntry property) +198

[DbUnexpectedValidationException: An unexpected exception was thrown during validation of 'PointEarnType' when invoking Foolproof.RequiredIfAttribute.IsValid. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.ValidationAttributeValidator.Validate(EntityValidationContext entityValidationContext, InternalMemberEntry property) +299
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.PropertyValidator.Validate(EntityValidationContext entityValidationContext, InternalMemberEntry property) +148
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.EntityValidator.ValidateProperties(EntityValidationContext entityValidationContext, InternalPropertyEntry parentProperty, List`1 validationErrors) +203
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.TypeValidator.Validate(EntityValidationContext entityValidationContext, InternalPropertyEntry property) +105
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.EntityValidator.Validate(EntityValidationContext entityValidationContext) +55
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.GetValidationResult(IDictionary`2 items) +299
   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.ValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary`2 items) +89
   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.GetValidationErrors() +289
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +107
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges() +53
   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges() +52
   MOU.Controllers.RDealsController.Create(R_Deals r_deals) in e:\MVC Projects\MouMvc\Controllers\RDealsController.cs:197
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +180
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +434
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +75
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +125
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +321
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +321
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +321
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +68
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +184
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +151
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +151
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +151
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9690164
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

What should I do in this case? Not getting actually where I am going wrong .

Please Help me! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Foolproof Validation has problems with EntityFramework.
For more details see [this bug report](https://foolproof.codeplex.com/workitem/15609)

Comment: Thanks. I saw that later!